# Install conda package from local file

Tags: python, gcc, package, conda, cython

I am trying to install a Python package from a local file in a Conda environment, but I'm having some trouble. I can't share the package, because it's not yet fully released.

To install this package, I need Cython, PyYAML and a C compiler installed (I'm using GCC). I've installed all of them in my Conda environment.

To install the package, several modules written in C and Cython need to be compiled. To do this, the package has a Install.py file. So, for installation inside my Conda environment, I need to execute

```bash
python3 Install.py -f
```

When I try to run this, unfortunately, I get this error:

```python
File "/home/artur/Documents/package/package-main/installation/Install.py", line 81, in <module>
    Installpackage ( )

  File "/home/artur/Documents/package/package-main/installation/Install.py", line 56, in Installpackage
    package.ProcessWithOptions ( options, report )

  File "/home/artur/Documents/package/package-main/installation/InstallUtilities.py", line 506, in ProcessWithOptions
    if options.doCLibraries: self.CompileCLibraries ( )

  File "/home/artur/Documents/package/package-main/installation/InstallUtilities.py", line 403, in CompileCLibraries
    os.rename ( os.path.join ( buildPath, "lib" + libraryName + _LibraryExtension ), os.path.join ( self.cLibraryPath, "lib" + libraryName + _LibraryExtension ) )

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.10/libdcCore.a' -> '/home/artur/Documents/package/package-main/pCore/__extensions__/clibrary/libdcCore.a'
```

I'm new to Conda, and I am not sure how to fix this error. I think it could be a problem with the `gcc` compiler inside the Conda environment, not being able to compile the code and create the `libdcCore.a` file.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: The error message you have given implies that a file doesn't exist do you can't copy it. It's possible that earlier error messages tell you about why the file doesn't exist, but we can't know. I think there's too much missing information here for anyone to help

Comment: I added a bit more information about the errors, maybe there is enough information with this.